# Hadoop and Custom Writable Issue

Tags: hadoop

I am using Hadoop 2.7 and I have got an issue when using a custom Writable "TextPair" (page 104 of the Definitive Guide). Basically, my program works fine when I am using just Text whereas it outputs "test.TextTuple@3b86249a    test.TextTuple@63cd18fd" when using the TextPair.

Please, Any idea of what is wrong with my code (below)?

============

Mapper1:

```
public class KWMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, TextTuple, TextTuple> {

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable k, Text v, Mapper.Context c) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String keywordRelRecord[] = v.toString().split(",");
        String subTopicID  = keywordRelRecord[0];
        String paperID    = keywordRelRecord[1];

        //set the KEY
        TextTuple key = new TextTuple();
        key.setNaturalKey(new Text(subTopicID));
        key.setSecondaryKey(new Text("K"));

        //set the VALUE
        TextTuple value = new TextTuple();
        value.setNaturalKey(new Text(paperID));
        value.setSecondaryKey(new Text("K"));

        c.write(key, value);
    }
```

Mapper2:

```
public class TDMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, TextTuple, TextTuple> {

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable k, Text v, Mapper.Context c) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String topicRecord[] = v.toString().split(",");
        String superTopicID = topicRecord[0];
        String subTopicID = topicRecord[1].substring(1, topicRecord[1].length() - 1);

        TextTuple key = new TextTuple();
        key.setNaturalKey(new Text(subTopicID));
        key.setSecondaryKey(new Text("T"));

        TextTuple value = new TextTuple();
        value.setNaturalKey(new Text(superTopicID));
        value.setSecondaryKey(new Text("T"));

        c.write(key, value);
    }
```

REDUCER :

```
public class TDKRReducer extends Reducer<TextTuple, TextTuple, Text, Text>{

    public void reduce(TextTuple k, Iterable<TextTuple> values, Reducer.Context c) throws IOException, InterruptedException{                 

        for (TextTuple val : values) {
            c.write(k.getNaturalKey(), val.getNaturalKey());
        }
    }

}
```

DRIVER:

```
public class TDDriver {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException {

        // This class support the user for the  configuration of the execution;
        Configuration confStage1 = new Configuration();

        Job job1 = new Job(confStage1, "TopDecKeywordRel");
        // Setting the driver class
        job1.setJarByClass(TDDriver.class);


        // Setting the input Files and processing them using the corresponding mapper class
        MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job1, new Path(args[0]), TextInputFormat.class, TDMapper.class);
        MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job1, new Path(args[1]), TextInputFormat.class, KWMapper.class);

        job1.setMapOutputKeyClass(TextTuple.class);
        job1.setMapOutputValueClass(TextTuple.class);

        // Setting the Reducer Class;
        job1.setReducerClass(TDKRReducer.class);
        // Setting the output class for the Key-value pairs

        job1.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job1.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        // Setting the output file 
        Path outputPA = new Path(args[2]);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job1, outputPA);

        // Submitting the Job Monitoring the execution of the Job
        System.exit(job1.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
        //conf.setPartitionerClass(CustomPartitioner.class);    
    }

}
```

CUSTOM VARIABLE

```
public class TextTuple implements Writable, WritableComparable<TextTuple> {

    private Text naturalKey;
    private Text secondaryKey;

    public TextTuple() {
        this.naturalKey = new Text();
        this.secondaryKey = new Text();
    }


    public void setNaturalKey(Text naturalKey) {
        this.naturalKey = naturalKey;
    }

    public void setSecondaryKey(Text secondaryKey) {
        this.secondaryKey = secondaryKey;
    }

    public Text getNaturalKey() {
        return naturalKey;
    }

    public Text getSecondaryKey() {
        return secondaryKey;
    }


    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
        naturalKey.write(out);
        secondaryKey.write(out);
    }

    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
        naturalKey.readFields(in);
        secondaryKey.readFields(in);
    }

    //This comparator controls the sort order of the keys.
    @Override   
    public int compareTo(TextTuple o) {
        // comparing the naturalKey
        int compareValue = this.naturalKey.compareTo(o.naturalKey);
        if (compareValue == 0) {
            compareValue = this.secondaryKey.compareTo(o.secondaryKey);
        }
        return -1 * compareValue; 
    }

}
```

Comment: problem solved. @Override missing in the reducer. Thanks